# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to create a React Native app with some basic routing.

This is my code so far:

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import MainScreen from './classes/MainScreen'


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Index: {
            screen: MainScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Index',
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
);

export default () => <AppNavigator />
```

MainScreen.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import HomeButton from './HomeButton'

export default class MainScreen extends Component {
    static navigatorOptions = {
        title: 'MyApp'
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={require('../img/logo.png')} style={{marginBottom: 20}} />
                <HomeButton text='Try me out' classType='first' />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})
```

HomeButton.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'


export default class HomeButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
                style={[baseStyle.buttons, styles[this.props.classType].style]}
            >
                <Text style={baseStyle.buttonsText}>{this.props.text.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions')
var windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const baseStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    buttons: {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        borderRadius: 2,
        width: windowWidth * 0.8,
        height: 50,
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.26,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5
    },
    buttonsText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        lineHeight: 50,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff'
    }
})

const styles = {
    first: StyleSheet.create({
        style: { backgroundColor: '#4caf50' }
    })
}
```

Everything works fine, but when pressing the button I get

> Can't find variable: navigate

I've read that I have to declare it like this:

```js
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
```

So I edited `HomeButton.js` and added that line at the beginning of the `render` function:

```js
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
            style={[baseStyle.buttons, styles[this.props.classType].style]}
        >
            <Text style={baseStyle.buttonsText}>{this.props.text.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Now I get:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

It seems that the `navigation` object is not coming into the properties, but I don't understand where should I get it from.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React-navigation` pass navigation prop to the screen components defined in the stack navigator.

So in your case, `MainScreen` can access `this.props.navigation` but `HomeButton` can't.

It should work if you pass navigation prop from `MainScreen` to `HomeButton` :

```
<HomeButton text='Try me out' classType='first' navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

Edit: You have to define the `Home`screen in your stack navigator in order to navigate to it, your `onPress={() => navigate('Home')}` won't work until then.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that prop to `HomeButton`, unfortunately I get the same error but inside `MainScreen.js`, in the `<HomeButton ...>` line.

Comment: That's weird, can you `console.log(this.props.navigation)` in your `MainScreen` `render()` ?

Comment: Nevermind. That was it. It wasn't refreshing the app on my phone. Once manually refreshed, it worked. Thank you!